# Random garbage ouput when trying to find the minimum distance between points in an array

Tags: c++, c++14, closest-points

**What's the fuss about?**

I'm trying to find the minimum distance between points (distance between 2 points in a 2D - plane: distance from `(x1, y1) to (y1, y2))`, which are stored in array `arr` and then calculate and return the minimum of those distances.

However, the problem is that my source code produces a random garbage output.

The idea is to get the distance between points `(x1, y1) and (x2, y2)` with the formula: 
`sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)`. 
To do this I select 4 elements for each iteration:
 `x1 = arr[0], x2 = arr[1], y1 = arr[2], y2 = arr[3]`.
`x1` and `x2` stays constant for each iteration (of `i`) while the distance between `x1, x2` and `y1, y2` (varies for every unique iteration of `j`) is calculated. Finally, the shortest distance between the two points are chosen and is returned to `main()`.

**What have I done to solve this mess?**

Including debugging statements in the source code reveals that the main culprit are the random garbage values (that shouldn't even exist, literally!).

Another culprit is that `sqrt(arg)` is giving out a random garbage value. For example, when calculating the distance between `(4, 4)` and `(1, 100)`, the result is `sqrt(0 + (-99)^2) = 99`. But instead it ouputs `-2147483648`.

**Here's my code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using std::sqrt;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
int dist_cal(vector<int>&, int);

int main()
{
    int num_pairs = -1;
    cout << "Enter the number of pairs of point co-ordinates (x, y) that you want to enter: " << endl;
    cin >> num_pairs;

    vector<int> points;
    cout << "Now enter the (x, y) co-ordinate pairs: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pairs * 2; i++)
    {
        int buff;
        cin >> buff;
        points.push_back(buff);
    }

    cout << "The minimum distance between the array of points entered is " << dist_cal(points, num_pairs) << "." << endl;
    return 0;
}

int dist_cal(vector<int>& arr, int num_pairs)
{
    int min_distance = -1, temp_distance = -1, x1, x2, y1, y2, itr_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num_pairs; i += 2)
    {
        x1 = arr[i + 0];
        x2 = arr[i + 1];
        for (int j = i + 2; j <= num_pairs; j += 2)
        {
            y1 = arr[j + 0];
            y2 = arr[j + 1];
            temp_distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2);
            if (itr_count == 0)
            {
                min_distance = temp_distance;
                itr_count++;
            }
            if (min_distance > temp_distance)
            {
                min_distance = temp_distance;
            }
        }
    }
    return min_distance;
}
```

I understand that this method is naive and O(n^2), but to move onto faster algorithms, I must first solve it with the most basic approach for mental sanity.

For an input:

```
4
4 4
7 8
1 100
4 4
```

the output should be `0`.

The actual output reads:
`The minimum distance between the array of points entered is -2147483648.`

What am I doing wrong here? Alternative (and more efficient algorithms) are also welcome! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have a typo in the following line : `int j = i + 2; i <= num_pairs; j += 2`, should be `j` instead of `i`. While acessing `vector` use `at` instead of `[]`, at `at` you will get exception when accessing out of bounds.

Comment: @rafix07 Yes! Thanks for pointing that  out! I'll edit the code. Now, the output is coming but it's a random garbage: ```-2147483648```.

Comment: @rafix07 Also, I realized I must have been blind and all my braincells must have been dead for the last 1 hour or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ `^` means XOR bitwise operation, if you want to rise `x1-x2` to the power of 2, you can write: `(x1-x2) * (x1 - x2)` or use `std::pow` function.

So this

```
sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2);
```

should be:

```
sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2));
```

---

Another issue, `sqrt` returns real number so `min_distance` and `temp_distance` should be `double` or `float`.

---

Your vector holds coordinates in this form: `x(i),y(i),..`

so this read

```
    x1 = arr[i + 0];
    x2 = arr[i + 1];
```

is wrong, and should be:

```
    x1 = arr[i + 0];
    y1 = arr[i + 1];
```

do the same in inner loop.

---

Also your inner loop should start at `0` index. And you have to detect a situation when for a given `p` point is calculated `distance(p,p)` (it is always 0) and skip this iteration. Then you will calculate all distances.

Comment: This problem is actually an assignment and the problem statement had the ```x1, x2``` notation like so. However, your assessment is correct in that ```x2``` is better read as ```y1```, corresponding to the co-ordinate axes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fixes suggested by [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019773/10910863), for this source code to work correctly, another change has to be made:

`for (int j = i + 2; j <= num_pairs; j += 2)`

should actually be:

`for (int j = i + 2; j <= num_pairs + 2; j += 2)`

This is because `i` can reach at most the value `4` for an input of `4` pairs (array size : `0` -> `7`). As `j` also depends on `i`, a total of `4` increments are performed on `i`. So `i` must be at most `4`, so that `x1 = 4, x2 = 5, y1 = 6`, and `y2 = 7`. On the other hand, `j` can be at most `6` for an input of `4` pairs (array size : `0` -> `7`). This is because if `i == 4`, and `j == 6`, then `y1 = 6` and `y2 = 7`, which is the last index in the vector `points`.